# Gorm element collections

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm working on an application that stores mountains by region.

```golang
type Mountain struct {
    Name     string
    Height   int
    RegionID int
}

type Region struct {
    ID        int64
    Name      string
    Mountains []Mountain
}
```

As you may see, I have an array of mountains with a foreign key constraint on `RegionID`. I'm trying on purpose to avoid setting ID on the mountains, in order to have them fully replaced when updating.

When I try to save the region:

```golang
var region = &models.Region{
    Name: "Lombardia",
    Mountains: []models.Mountain{
        {
            Name:   "Pizzo Coca",
            Height: 3050,
        },
        {
            Name:   "Bernina",
            Height: 4049,
        },
    },
}

db.Create(region)
```

I have this error:

```
ERRORE: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE richiede una specifica di inferenza o il nome di un vincolo 
(SQLSTATE 42601)
```

I know that is not in english, but I can't find the english version on the net.

Comment: Could you also post how the tables were created?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Upsert / On Conflict](https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Upsert-On-Conflict), as example:

```
import "gorm.io/gorm/clause"

// Do nothing on conflict
db.Clauses(clause.OnConflict{DoNothing: true}).Create(&user)
```

Some info in [this article](https://www.it-swarm.it/it/postgresql/gestione-dei-conflitti-di-postgres-con-molteplici-vincoli-univoci/824611958/)